# Grails searchable plugin errors mapping hasMany

Tags: grails, plugins, has-many, searchable

I"m using  0.6.3 of searchable and grails-1.3.7.  If I do not map the Domain hasMany properties thing work fine.  However, if I map a hasMany property like the example in the documentation:

http://www.grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Mapping+-+Class+Property+Mapping

```
 comments component: true
```

or

```
 keywords index: 'not_analyzed'
```

in the searchable closure, I get this error

```
2011-10-10 15:20:53,788 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'compassGps': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'compass' while setting bean property 'compass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to map [com.ace.mws.servicetemplates.ServiceTemplate.services]. It does not appear to a suitable 'searchable property' (normally simple types like Strings, Dates, Numbers, etc), 'searchable reference' (normally another domain class) or 'searchable component' (normally another domain class defined as a component, using the 'embedded' declaration). Is it a derived property (a getter method with no equivalent field) defined with 'def'? Try defining it with a more specific return type
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compassGps': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'compass' while setting bean property 'compass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to map [com.ace.mws.servicetemplates.ServiceTemplate.services]. It does not appear to a suitable 'searchable property' (normally simple types like Strings, Dates, Numbers, etc), 'searchable reference' (normally another domain class) or 'searchable component' (normally another domain class defined as a component, using the 'embedded' declaration). Is it a derived property (a getter method with no equivalent field) defined with 'def'? Try defining it with a more specific return type
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure8_closure14.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:263)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure8_closure14.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure8.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:299)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure8.call(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure8.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:245)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:35)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to map [com.ace.mws.servicetemplates.ServiceTemplate.services]. It does not appear to a suitable 'searchable property' (normally simple types like Strings, Dates, Numbers, etc), 'searchable reference' (normally another domain class) or 'searchable component' (normally another domain class defined as a component, using the 'embedded' declaration). Is it a derived property (a getter method with no equivalent field) defined with 'def'? Try defining it with a more specific return type
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to map [com.ace.mws.servicetemplates.ServiceTemplate.services]. It does not appear to a suitable 'searchable property' (normally simple types like Strings, Dates, Numbers, etc), 'searchable reference' (normally another domain class) or 'searchable component' (normally another domain class defined as a component, using the 'embedded' declaration). Is it a derived property (a getter method with no equivalent field) defined with 'def'? Try defining it with a more specific return type
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.invokeMethod(ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.groovy:217)
        at com.ace.mws.servicetemplates.ServiceTemplate$__clinit__closure1.doCall(ServiceTemplate.groovy:6)
        at com.ace.mws.servicetemplates.ServiceTemplate$__clinit__closure1.doCall(ServiceTemplate.groovy)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.searchableGetCompassClassPropertyMappings(ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.groovy:97)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.this$3$searchableGetCompassClassPropertyMappings(ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.groovy)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.getCompassClassMapping(ClosureSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.groovy:129)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.CompositeSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.getCompassClassMapping(CompositeSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.java:93)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.AbstractSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.getCompassClassMapping(AbstractSearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassClassMapper.java:52)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.mapping.SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator.configureMappings(SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator.java:80)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator.configure(DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:131)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator.configure(CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:39)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.buildCompass(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:93)
        at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:58)
        ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue.  The popular workarounds are either not mapping the `hasMany` fields (as you mentioned) or using `merge(flush:true)` on your object instance before `save(flush:true)` is called.  I found not mapping the `hasMany` fields to be more effective and less of a headache since using `merge(flush:true)` can cause duplicate objects in some situations and also requires you manually maintain the search index.  Read more about the issue [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSEARCHABLE-60).

Comment: If I do not map the hasMany then is there any way to index them?  The Grails Searchable Plugin default web page will not let my search on the hasMany, but does allow searches on the simple Strings.

Comment: I tried to not index it but I get the same error.  static searchable = { tags index: 'no' }